# Saving PHP session variables between domains and https/http

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a checkout form that posts to authorize.net to approve a transaction and then displays a receipt page back on my server. However, session variables set on the checkout page are not carried over to the receipt page. How can I save session variables when the user is redirected to an external https domain and then back?

If I save the variables to a database, how do I even identify which data is associated with the user if the session variable with the username is lost!?

Comment: This is strange. As long as your checkout form and receipt page are on the same server, same domain, and protocol, the session variables should still be available. Double check?

Comment: That is what I assumed. I have double checked. I just can't figure out why the variables are dropping...

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to call session_start() on your receipt page? (Just checking :) )

Comment: Well I'm stumped, unfortunately. Wish I could help more. In the meantime, does Authorize.NET let you specify redirect urls? Maybe tell it to redirect to "receipt.php?transactionID={unique_id}" and you can pull from database.

Comment: Ok so I have just discovered that the session variables are working but only on some computers. I have tested it on 3 systems and it only doesn't work on the one. Is their a local setting that could be messing with the session??

Comment: Perhaps. What browser are you using? Check to see if you have cookies enabled, and your app is in authorized domain. Also, do you have a self-signed certificate? Maybe if you don't have a trusted certificate it automatically disables cookies for you.

Comment: Chrome and firefox work. It seems safari does not. There is no certificate.

Comment: In safari, do you have www subdomain in your url? Is it consistent before and after? I suspect Chrome/Firefox does some funky stuff with the www (removing it). Could you be going from www.site.com/checkout.php to site.com/receipt.php ?

Comment: great insight! I will look into it!

Comment: Good luck. I'm out of ideas to be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with session not working just on one browser. Turns out I apparently had too many cookies for that host, clearing them solved the problem.